# Why do we receive an undefined Event error when streaming payments via the node.js sdk?

Tags: horizon, javascript-sdk

We run a continuous payments stream that receives fairly useless errors on the regular and would like to know what these may stem from and if they can be disregarded. I haven't been able to correlate these errors with error logs on our Horizon server. Below is the error being logged in node.js via the `onerror` callback:

```
Event { type: 'error', message: undefined }
```

Below is the source code that is triggering this error event:

```
    server
        .payments()
        .cursor('now')
        .stream({
            onerror: (error) => {
                if (error.messaged !== undefined) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            },
            onmessage: (payment) => {
                if (payment.type_i !== 1) {
                    return;
                }

                // ... code to handle payment ...
            }
        });
```

Just to reiterate my question(s):

- Why are we getting these errors from the stream?
- Are these errors something we should be worried about?
- How do we stop receiving these errors?

Comment: did you try with transactions? do you get the same error?

Comment: Have observed the same on public and private Horizon instances (they behave exactly the same). All payments are found however and it looks like the errors can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on your own Horizon server, it might just be that you haven't upgraded to the latest version.

Before a recent change was done, event streams were closed by the server once every 45(?) seconds or so, giving you an error.